# What sides are the major Game of Thrones houses on going into S8E5?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Which of the 7 major houses or even minor ones are on each side of the upcoming conflict? From my understanding until now it should be:

- Starks and Arryns with Daenerys
- Presumably Baratheons with Daenerys

  > Since Gendry is legitimised by her decree.

But I guess it doesn't really count since he doesn't have any actual houses with them from Storm's End, but are the houses from Storm's End on Cersei's side instead?

And I would guess that Casterly Rock is still under Daenerys' rule, but all the Lannisters moved to King's Landing instead.

Last episode they talked about Dorne as well having a new Prince but they choose not to contact him so I guess they are neutral in the conflict.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Dany's side

- **Starks** - Led by Jon Snow the Stark forces declared for the Targaryens and pledged their forces to Dany.
- **Arryns** - Led by Lord Yohn Royce, until Robin Arryn comes of age, they have pledged for House Stark, mainly Sansa, and so by default are for House Targaryen.
- **Greyjoys** - Only a small faction of the Grejoys have pledged for House Targaryen, led by Yara Greyjoy and formerly Theon Greyjoy.
- **Dorne** (house unclear) - Whilst the Sand Snakes previously pledged for House Targaryen, they were wiped out. However, it is revealed the new Prince of Dorne also pledges for House Targaryen, which is hardly surprising, though what that support entails, if anything, is unclear.

  > **Varys:** The new Prince of Dorne pledges his support.
  >
  > <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 4, "The Last of the Starks"</sub>
- **Baratheons** - The Baratheon line continues on through Gendry, if you recognise Dany legitimising him as official. However, he does not control the Baratheon forces, if any.

### Cersei's side

- **Lannisters** - Obviously, she has the support of her own house.
- **Greyjoys** - The bulk of the Greyjoy fleet is under Euron Greyjoy's command and he supports House Lannister.

### Unclear

- **Baratheons** - The Baratheon leadership was wiped out and the forces scattered, it is unclear who, if anyone, is still in control of them.
- **Tyrells** - Whilst they originally declared for House Targaryen, the Tyrell's were wiped out when Jaime and the Lannister forces took Highgarden and killed Olenna, destroying House Tyrell. It is unclear who any of the remaining forces fight for.
- **Tullys** - Whilst allied with the Starks through Catelyn's marriage to Ned, it is unclear who they fight for now as Edmure is a captive of the Lannisters.
- **Freys** - Whilst they allied with House Lannister to betray the Starks, Arya wiped out the majority of them and so it is unclear who the remaining forces fight for as their leadership has been wiped out.
- **Tarlys** - Randyll and Dickon sided with the Lannisters but were killed by Dany. However, some of the surviving forces agreed to join Dany's side. Of those that weren't captured they are likely still under Lannister control. So the remaining forces would be split across both. We also have Sam still alive but he gave up his rights to his house and there's been no indication he has any control over the armies anyway.

Comment: Of course Cersei also has the support of the Golden Company and Dany has the support of the Unsullied and Dothraki but that's out of scope of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was what I was looking for, though it is so sad that it is so unclear with most of the houses, would have expected a clearer picture since they did so much world building but are now focusing on just 3 houses. But are all Lannisters on Cersei's side since both of the possible heirs of house Lannister are presumably on Daeneris side, and male heirs are of greatest importance in the 7 kingdoms?

Comment: @starseeker29 Yes the Lannister forces are with Cersei, remember that Tyrion fled Westeros to avoid execution and when Jaime leaves, alone, he is named a traitor by Cersei. He also ends up at Winterfell alone implying no one joined him on his way north.

Comment: Gendry Baratheon is with Dany I guess ;)

Comment: @AnkurRathee Aye but will he be able to rally any of the remaining forces to him? And at the moment he hasn't done that so in context of the question my point stands will update to be a little clearer here though.

Comment: I suppose the Tarlys could be on Dany's side too through Sam although they too were basically wiped out by Dany and Sam took the black and can't take the House mantel up...

Comment: @VerasVitas Good point, meant to add them in but forgot.

Comment: The defunct houses are not likely to add any actual support to either side. The holdings of those houses would revert to whomever sits on the Iron Throne. While there are certainly some remaining forces associated with those houses still around, they aren't likely to be organized. Unless you can arm, feed, and (probably) pay them, they will find some other job that comes with a paycheck. It's also likely that more than a few have gone mercenary and allied with the Lannisters. It would be inaccurate to call that support of any particular house.